# Read SAS sas7bdat data with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, sas

I have a SAS table and I try to read it with Spark. I've try to use this https://github.com/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat like but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("my_table.sas7bdat")
```

It returns this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o878.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.github.saurfang.sas.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.saurfang.sas.spark.DefaultSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the package was not imported correctly. You have to use `--packages saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.10` when running `spark-submit` or `pyspark`. See: https://spark-packages.org/package/saurfang/spark-sas7bdat

You could also download the JAR file from that page, and run your pyspark or spark-submit command with `--jars /path/to/jar`

Answer (score 1):

I've just sorted this issue out in R, and I bet my 2 cents it's the same issue here. The problem seems to be that the correct repository for `com.github.saurfang.sas.spark` is unavailable/not specified. It should be `https://repos.spark-packages.org/`

We're all stumped because the error to the console here (and in R) is only slightly informative and relates to this part

```
Failed to find data source: com.github.saurfang.sas.spark
```

When I ran the R call to spark-submit in cmd (I'm using Windows), low-and-behold, it showed the attempts at trying to download the `com.github.saurfang.sas.spark` from various caches and repos, but not the one referenced above..

Thus fixing it all, resulted in this call and download of the spark package (using sparklyr in R)..

`spark-submit2.cmd --driver-memory 32G --name sparklyr --class sparklyr.Shell --packages "saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.11" --repositories https://repos.spark-packages.org/ "...\sparklyr\java\sparklyr-2.0-2.11.jar" 8880 41823`

Comment: Thanks, this and https://therinspark.com/contributing.html helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the above two methods but didn't work for me as the data frame is not accessible even for df.count() and throws up an error. I had a 5768 X 6432 data frame.

**Solution:** 
Convert sas7bdat into flat file CSV or txt with a delimiter of your choice I have done it on txt with pipe delimiter as my data could have had commas.

**read the sas7bdat and use it to get the schema.**

```
df= spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("PATH/SAS_DATA.sas7bdat")
vartype = df.schema
```

**now pass this schema when reading txt file**

```
df2 = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','True').option('delimiter','|').schema(vartype).load("path/SAS_DATA.txt")
```

Works for me

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?  It looks more like a new topic to me.

Comment: It's seems like it only because you are required to create a text version for the corresponding sas7bdat file but in the end it does solve the issue of reading sas7bdat file with same schema. Simply reading the sas7bdat data through saurfang didn't work for me correctly but this does.

Comment: Have you added any package to read a sas7bdat file?

Comment: Yes, loading the saurfang package while initiating the spark-submit
 spark-submit --packages saurfang:spark-sas7bdat:2.0.0-s_2.10